# jqGrid. Handle OnSave event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I use simple (non-tree) grid, inline editing, data, recieved from server.
I need my function to be called after any saving takes place (create new, edit exists).

Comment: You should explain more clear what you mean under onSave event. Do you make editing or export of data. If editing then which one: inline editing, form editing, cell editing? Which datatype you use? Do you use tree grid, subgrids and so on? Do you hold the data local or get from the server and so on. The definition of jqGrid could also explain many things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `aftersavefunc` parameter of the [editrow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#editrow) function which you use for the [inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing). If you don't need some parameter which are used before the `aftersavefunc` parameter you should use `null` excepting `{}` for the `extraparam` parameter (see [the source code of the editrow](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L12)).

Comment: Thanks! But I forgot to write about creating. When I create new record using popup, it would be good to have an ability to handle onSave, too. I'll accept your solution although you answer or not, but it would be great to know...

Comment: @JooLio: As "create new record using popup" you mean probably `editGridRow` with `"new"` as the first argument. It has many [events](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) which you can use like `onclickSubmit`, `beforeSubmit`, `afterSubmit` and so on. If you use "Add" form with respect of [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition) you should use `prmAdd` parameter like `jQuery("#grid_id").navGrid('#gridpager',{/*parameters*/},{/*prmEdit*/}, {/*prmAdd*/onclickSubmit:function(opt,postdata){alert("onSave");return {};});`